# Hide elements in Sheets or Revit Document

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit, revit-2015

I am Having a doubt in Revit API. I want to hide some elements in Sheets of the Revit document. But I need an Active view to hide that. `view.HideElements(ids)` If I take a view which is active and try to hide elements in it, I am getting exception `TypeError: expected View, got SectionView`. Is there any way to hide that ? or is there any way to make my SectionView as Active View?

Help me with this. Either in Python or Dynamo Script(Design Script) or C#

I am trying to hide elements in Sheets In Revit Architecture Software but if the sheet is in Active View I can hide easily by taking the active view. If I take Sheets from FilteredElementCollector and try to hide elements in that, It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Found The Way in Python

```
TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(document)
TransactionManager.Instance.ForceCloseTransaction()

uiDocument.RequestViewChange(view)
```

RequestViewChange is the Revit API method which can change the view of the UI-Document. Sometimes document won't allow to change the view while a transaction is going on so I force closed the Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Autodesk.Revit.UI.UIDocument`

the `UIDocument` has a property named `ActiveView` which has a `get` and `set` options.
Use the `UIdocument` to set the active view to the view you need and then make the changes you want.

and take care that setting the Active View Property requires a separate `Transaction`.

Refer to this https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/b6adb74b-39af-9213-c37b-f54db76b75a3.htm